# 8 bytes scraped off scapy payload from UDP

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

I am sending udp packet using scapy. I am seeing first 8 bytes scraped off from the payload. Any reasons why?

```
payload = '{ "dcgdsfjfghtimec": ' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.%f')) + ', "sequence": ' + str(sequenceNum)+'}'
packet = IP(dst="127.0.0.1", src="10.0.0.1")/UDP(dport=5555)/Raw(load=json.dumps(payload))
```

On receiver side:

```
def packet_callback(packet):
    if packet[UDP].payload:
        pkt = str(packet[UDP].payload)
        
while True:
    sniff(filter="dst port 5555", prn=packet_callback, store=0)
```

I am observing the payload on the server side:

```
(Pdb) p packet[UDP].payload
<DNS  id=8827 qr=0 opcode=4 aa=0 tc=0 rd=0 ra=0 z=1 ad=0 cd=1 rcode=12 qdcount=8804 ancount=25447 nscount=25715 arcount=26218 qd='' an='' ns='' ar='' |<Raw  load='fghtimec\\": 33:44.120154, \\"sequence\\": 0}"' |>>
```

While on client side after sending a packet:

```
(Pdb) p packet
<IP  frag=0 proto=udp src=10.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 |<UDP  dport=rplay |<Raw  load='"{ \\"dcgdsfjhtimec\\": 32:49.187705, \\"sequence\\": 0}"' |>>>
```

Exactly 8 bytes, stripped off from server side..why?

Any idea will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Sudip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scapy's default UDP port value is 53, for both source and destination. This causes the destination to interpret the beginning of the payload as a `DNS()` layer. So the bytes are not missing, they are just interpreted as a (broken) DNS layer.

You can reproduce this locally (replace `raw()` by `str()` if you are using Scapy < 2.4.0) by having a look at `IP(raw(packet))`: `raw()` forces Scapy to create the bytes it would send on the newtork, and `IP()` tells Scapy to dissect the bytes as an IP layer.

You can "fix" that by using a different source port (since you already changed the destination port): `packet = IP(dst="127.0.0.1", src="10.0.0.1")/UDP(sport=12345, dport=5555)/Raw(load=json.dumps(payload))`.

As a side note, in my opinion you have another (real, this one) problem: you probably don't want to `json.dumps()` the string but a Python object instead (with your current code, you encode the data as JSON twice, since the string you use is already JSON encoded):

```
payload = {"dcgdsfjfghtimec": datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.%f'),
                      "sequence": sequenceNum}
packet = IP(dst="127.0.0.1", src="10.0.0.1")/UDP(sport=12345, dport=5555)/Raw(load=json.dumps(payload))
```